# Found a mistake in the PHP Master Write Cutting-Edge Code?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am reading SitePoint's book *PHP Master Write Cutting-Edge Code*; on page 119 (Chapter 3, APIs) the authors say:

> For the example URL http://example.com/events, the value of $controller_name becomes EventController and, since it’s a GET request, the $action_name is GETAction().

The code is:

```
// initialize the request object and store the requested URL
$request = new Request();
$request->url_elements = array();
if(isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
  $request->url_elements = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
}
// figure out the verb and grab the incoming data
$request->verb = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
switch($request->verb) {
  case 'GET':
    $request->parameters = $_GET;
    break;
  case 'POST':
  case 'PUT':
    $request->parameters = json_decode(file_get_contents➥ ('php://input'), 1);
    break;
  case 'DELETE':
  default:
    // we won't set any parameters in these cases
    $request->parameters = array();
}

// route the request
if($request->url_elements) {
$controller_name = ucfirst($request->url_elements[1]) .➥ 'Controller';
  if(class_exists($controller_name)) {
    $controller = new $controller_name();
    $action_name = ucfirst($request->verb) . "Action";
    $response = $controller->$action_name($request);
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    $response = "Unknown Request for " . $request->url_elements[1];
  }
} else {
  header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
  $response = "Unknown Request";
}
```

They use a `RewriteRule` of the Apache mod_rewrite module in an .htaccess file so that every request where the requested resource doesn't exist (not a file and not a dir) passes through an *index.php* script located at the document root of the server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So the request to http://example.com/events is passed to `example.com/index.php/events` with `/events` as PATH_INFO.

Not that I want to look finicky, but shouldn't the `EventController` be an `EventsController` because they split the PATH_INFO var and use the `$request->url_elements[1]` which will be *events* and not *event*?

Comment: Is this a question or an erratum report? If the latter, it is probably best reported to the authors. Book authors sometimes have a GitHub account, where a ticket or a patch can be raised.

Comment: Yes maybe you are right, I just wanted to be sure that I haven't miss something that cause it's a new topic for me, thank you anyway!

Comment: Now that Sumaria8 agrees it is an erratum, please do report it to the author - it won't get into the next reprint if no-one raises it.

Comment: Yes I'll do that now thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the writer of the book seems to have made a typo. `ucfirst($request->url_elements[1]) . 'Controller';` would indeed evaluate to `EventsController` for the url `http://example.com/events`.